# How to give a function a return value when the return is inside an if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I had a function that was initially like this, and worked:

```
  productGroupPages(): PDF.Page[] {
    const descriptions = {};
    this.areas.forEach(area => descriptions[area.id] = area.description);
    return this.json.engagementAreas.map(area => {
      return this.productGroupPage(area, descriptions[area.id]);
    });
  }
```

Basically everything isnt wrapped in the for each.

I had to alter to the function as i wanted to go through a for each, to then use an if statement so i would only return values that actually contained a certain value, the result is that my return statement is too early, I cant move it to the end because of the for loop and im struggling to find out how I can get past this,

this new function:

```
  productGroupPages(): PDF.Page[] {
    const descriptions = {};
    let pages = {};
    console.log('this .json' + JSON.stringify(this.json))
    this.json.engagementAreas.forEach(area => {
      descriptions[area.id] = area.description

      if (area.engagementTypes.length !== 0) {

        return this.json.engagementAreas.map(area => {
          return this.productGroupPage(area, descriptions[area.id]);
        });
      }
    })
  }
```

I tried creating a variable, an array or object and equaling that to the return value and then returning that near the end of the scope but this wouldnt let me it said the return type was wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of an example input and the expected output from it?

Comment: there is a `return` inside the `.forEach()` but that doesn't do anything, as `.forEach()` ignores the returned values and doesn't return anything itself. You seem to want to do `.filter()` followed by `.map()` rather than `.forEach()`

Comment: **Note:** `Array.forEach` does not return anything

Comment: @Rajesh and now that I look at the changed code - neither does the function itself. It used to return the result of `.map()` now it just exectues a `.forEach()` and doesn't even have a `return` statement there.

Comment: I suggest you do `this.json.engagementAreas.forEach(area => {
            if (area.engagementTypes.length !== 0) { descriptions[area.id] = area.description } })` and then loop over descriptions

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I don't understand the changes made. It seems like the only thing needed was to add the `if` statement inside the `forEach` to filter out some of the results. Or to chain `.filter()` -> `.forEach()` for the same effect. I don't see why the `.map()` call was moved inside the `.forEach()` logic, especially since it now doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments, I had over complicated it. I now know I can return a value and then .filter or .map on the result, to return a final value. So I didnt need the initial forEach loop, I think this will be great for others to see. Lesson learnt, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your initial code, with the `forEach` and `map` separated was very clean!

The problem with your new code, is that using `return` inside `.forEach()` does not make sense in javascript ;) Whenever you return from `.forEach()`, javascript just ignores the result:

```
let result = [1,2,3].forEach(x => {
  return x * 2;
});
result // undefined
```

I think you wanted to only return some `area`-s, which you can do with `array.filter()` like this:

```
productGroupPages(): PDF.Page[] {
  const descriptions = {};
  this.areas.forEach(area => descriptions[area.id] = area.description);
  return this.json.engagementAreas
    .filter(area => area.engagementTypes.length !== 0)
    .map(area => {
      return this.productGroupPage(area, descriptions[area.id]);
    });
}
```

I hope that is actually what you meant to do, and if so, I hope this works :)

Comment: Hey, I like how the return is made on json.engagements and THEN the data is manipulated. I was wondering how many pages were created by this but the .map creates an array of the this.productGroupPage results.